# For a list of references is it better to give full links to a research group or just the address to the faculty homepage?

Tags: job-search, recommendation-letter, application-cover-letter

I am in the process of writing a contact list of my references. I noticed a inconsistency in how the different individuals include links as a reference (e.g. in mail signatures or business cards). Essentially there are two options when providing a link:

1. to the specific pages of the research group or individual
2. to the department/faculty pages to which the individual or research group belongs.

Option 1 *feels* more appropriate as it provides a **direct** access to the person who's supposed to be contacted. However, this option typically has the negative drawback of having a long, often **ugly** links containing many encoding characters. These links typically break the visual appearance of the document.

Option 2 alleviates that problem by problem by providing a short and clean address, however implies that the reader has to dig into the faculty/department pages to find the person/group that is being referred to.

I have considered link shorteners but that does not feel legitimate in such a document. If I was a recruiter I would be vary of a short random link of a document.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how there is one correct answer to this question - it would appear to be entirely personal preference. If the list is for use by somebody else, I would go with whatever the person provided in their signature/business card - they have weighed in with their preference.

Comment: @JonCuster I understand your point, fair enough. But the same rationale ("whether or not there is one correct answer") could easily be applied to any CV related question here.